# Hertzian contact mechanics: symbolically calculating the required force for a specific displacement

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, special-functions

Consider two parallel Cylinders with Diameters of $R_1$ and $R_2$:

> [image: Contact between Two Cylinders with Parallel Axes]

The contact width can be calculated from 2D Hertz formula:

$$ a=2 \sqrt{\frac{PR}{\pi E_c}} \tag{1}$$

Where $P=\frac{F}{L}$ is the force per unit length, and

$$\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\tag{2}$$

and
$$\frac{1}{E_c}=\frac{1-\nu_1^2}{E_1}+\frac{1-\nu_2^2}{E_2}\tag{3}$$

From [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-76-multi-scale-system-design-fall-2004/readings/lec12cont_read.pdf) I know the total displacement can be written as:

$$ \delta=\frac{P}{\pi E_c}\left( \ln\left(\frac{8R_1}{a} \right)+\ln\left(\frac{8R_2}{a} \right)-1 \right) \tag{4}$$

I need to calculate $P$ as a function of $\delta$ so :

```
R := (R1*R2)/(R1 + R2)
a := 2*Sqrt[P*R/(pi*Ec)]
Solve[delta == P*(Log[8*R1/a] + Log[8*R2/a] - 1)/(pi*Ec), P]
```

Which gives me "a" solution and a warning:

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> [image]

To have a general understanding of the solution I plotted a simplified version:

```
Plot[-x/ProductLog[-x], {x, 0, 1/E}]
```

> [image]

Which does not make sense because at $\delta=0$ the force must be zero, and it must increase by displacement increasing.

Trying to solve the equation with `Reduce`, as sugested in the waring:

```
Reduce[delta == P*(Log[8*R1/a] + Log[8*R2/a] - 1)/(pi*Ec), P]
```

also does not yield any results after a long time of calculation. I would appreciate if you could help me know if I'm making any mistakes and/or how to calculate $P$ versus $\delta$ for parallel cylinders.

Comment: If you add `Reals` as domain specification into `Reduce`, you are quickly able to see that Mathematica admits it cannot solve for P using `Reduce`.

Comment: I actually did that. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: There is typo in pi. E is in-build command so you  have to replace with another symbole

Comment: @GopalVerma ah! silly mistake. I'm gonna fix that and come back here to report.

Comment: @GopalVerma I can't find the pi typo. where is it?

Comment: `Pi` should be capitalized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this takes a bit of extra work.. first factor the lead `P` into a new symbol ( `deltabyp` ) and solve:

```
R = (R1*R2)/(R1 + R2);
a = 2*Sqrt[P*R/(Pi*Ec)];
sol = Solve[deltabyp == (Log[8*R1/a] + Log[8*R2/a] - 1)/(Pi*Ec), 
   P][[1]]
```

> {P -> 16 E^(-1 - deltabyp Ec Pi) Ec Pi (R1 + R2)}

now sub back in for `deltabyp` and `Reduce` yields a pretty reasonable form:

```
 Simplify[Reduce[(P /. sol /. deltabyp -> delta/P  ) == P, P, Reals], 
   Assumptions -> {R1 > 0, R2 > 0, Ec > 0, delta > 0}]
```

> [image]

plot the two solutions:

```
With[{R1 = 1, R2 = 1, Ec = 1}, 
 Plot[{
  -((delta Ec \[Pi])/ProductLog[-((delta E)/(16 (R1 + R2)))]),
  -((delta Ec \[Pi])/ProductLog[-1, -((delta E)/(16 (R1 + R2)))])},
  {delta, 0, 16 (R1 + R2)/E^2}]]
```

[image]

so you see the desired result is the second one,

> [image]

note that `ProductLog` is mathematica's name for the `Lambert-W` function.

```
 (P/.%)//TraditionalForm
```

$$\implies P=-\frac{\pi \delta E_c}{W_{-1}\left(- \frac{e \delta}{16\left( R_1 +R_2 \right)} \right)}$$

They curiously avoid mentioning that in the docs for `ProductLog` , however there is an undocumented `LambertW` that simplifies to `ProductLog`

Comment: What is the `[[1]]` at the end of the `Solve`?

Comment: solve returns a list of solutions, in this case there is only one solution, so the `[[1]]` effectively gets rid of an extra set of `{ }`.

Comment: I do not understand the concept of `ProductLog[k,z]`. What does it mean?

Comment: How one can write it in the form of  [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it but still don't know how to describe the `ProductLog[k,z]` in terms of `Lambert-W function`. I know $y=W(x)$ is Lambert-W function where $x=ye^y$. but what is `ProductLog[k,z]`?

Comment: my understanding `ProductLog[-1, z]` *is* `LambertW[-1, z]`  which is `W` subscript `-1` on the wiki page.

Comment: @Foad You can think of $W$ like you do $\sqrt{\cdot}$. Both give you a solution to a certain equation; $W(x)$ satisfies $ x = W(x) \exp{W(x)}$, and $\sqrt{x}$ satisfies $x = (\sqrt{x})^2$. However, $-\sqrt{x}$ _also_ satisfies the second equation. It turns out that, similarly, there are multiple solutions to $y=xe^x$, so if you want $W$ to return an unambiguous number (i.e., be a bona fide function), you need to specify which of the multiple solutions you would like. $k$ is an index that lets you do this.

Comment: @sourisse thanks. but what a negative index mean? here the solution has a -1 index. it is confusing!

Comment: @Foad It doesn't "mean" anything, it's just a convention. You could just as well have called it the $\star$th solution, as long as everybody agreed on which one that was. You can blame Knuth et. al for popularizing this notation: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02124750

Comment: @sourisse that was the main core of confusion. at least we have someone to blame now :) . Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Foad: the Lambert function is just like the logarithm, in that it also has many (complex-valued) branches. But, the logarithm only has one real branch (what we call `Log[]` in *Mathematica*), while `ProductLog[]` has two real branches, `ProductLog[0, x] == ProductLog[x]` (the *principal branch*) and `ProductLog[-1, x]`. Your situation just happened to be one where the non-principal real branch was needed.